# Google Analytics: Exit page report differs from conversions

Tags: google-analytics, reporting, exit-pages

I have an issue determining my checkout pages exit percentage.

Looking at the site's database event information for a single day I am given the following information:

1. Entered checkout - 306
2. Completed Checkout - 249
3. 81% completed (completed / entered checkout)
4. 19% exited (remainder)

When I look at my reporting in Google analytics I am given the following information:

1. Entered checkout - 304
2. Completed checkout - 247
3. Exits - 26
4. Exit % - 0.09% (exits / entered checkout)

So what reason would there be for my Exit % to be different than the math between the difference of entered and completed checkout?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Analytics has its own way to calculate metrics that can differ from other platforms. At this point, is important to understand [how they calculate exit percentage](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2525491?hl=en):

> For all pageviews to the page, Exit Rate is the percentage that was the last in the session.

I assume in your checkout process the URL is always the same, is that right? In that case, in order to calculate the exit rate, Analytics takes the total number of exits from each page (26) in relation to the total number of page views for that URL (304). Then divides the exits by the page views and calculates the percentage.

```
26/304 = 0,09%
```

Comment: The URL does stay the same, correct. I was thinking more about this over night and maybe you can confirm my thoughts sound reasonable. The potential different between the first set of metrics vs the second set is because the first set is measuring the number of people who start the checkout process and leave the site in total. Where the second set of metrics is showing the exit percentage strictly from the checkout page. Does that sound probable?

Comment: "Where the second set of metrics is showing the exit percentage strictly from the checkout page". That's is, you are correct.